# how to use jquery selector to select id of django template variable value?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a django web app.
In the html page, some element id in the for loop used django template variable value, as in the for loop every line should have different id value.

But in the below jquery, when I tried to use selector, the django template variable value could not be selected(obj.title here in my case).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

{% for obj in query_results_book %}
<td>
                                <select name="keep_discard" id="keep_discard" onchange="GetVal(this)">
                                <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
                                <option value="Discard">Discard</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="discard_reason" id="{{obj.title}}">
                                <option value="Change edition">Change edition</option>
                                <option value="Change to eTextbook">Change to eTextbook</option>
                                <option value="Change title">Change title</option>
                                <option value="No material required">No material required</option>
                            </select>
</td>
{%endfor%}

<script>
    
                function GetVal(obj){
    
                var index = obj.selectedIndex;
    
                if(index == 1){
                    $("#obj.title").show();
                }
                else{
                    $("#obj.title ").hide();
                }
            }

</script>
```

Now the js script could not work for the query selector, it does not select my element.
How could I let the jquery selector select some id, which is my django template variable value?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please post the RENDERED HTML

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique

Just delegate - this code does not need any ID

```js
$("#tableId").on("change", "[name=keep_discard]", function() {
  $(this).closest("td").find("[name=discard_reason]").toggle(this.value === "Discard")
});
```

```css
[name=discard_reason] { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableId">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="keep_discard">
        <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
        <option value="Discard">Discard</option>
      </select>
      <select name="discard_reason">
        <option value="Change edition">Change edition</option>
        <option value="Change to eTextbook">Change to eTextbook</option>
        <option value="Change title">Change title</option>
        <option value="No material required">No material required</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="keep_discard">
        <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
        <option value="Discard">Discard</option>
      </select>
      <select name="discard_reason">
        <option value="Change edition">Change edition</option>
        <option value="Change to eTextbook">Change to eTextbook</option>
        <option value="Change title">Change title</option>
        <option value="No material required">No material required</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="keep_discard">
        <option value="Keep">Keep</option>
        <option value="Discard">Discard</option>
      </select>
      <select name="discard_reason">
        <option value="Change edition">Change edition</option>
        <option value="Change to eTextbook">Change to eTextbook</option>
        <option value="Change title">Change title</option>
        <option value="No material required">No material required</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```